# Does * have side effect in Python regular expression matching?

Tags: python, regex

I'm learning Python's regular expression, following is working as I expected:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('\s+|:', 'find   a str:s2')
['find', 'a', 'str', 's2']
```

But when I change `+` to `*`, the output is weird to me:

```
>>> re.split('\s*|:', 'find  a str:s2')
['find', 'a', 'str:s2']
```

How is such pattern interpreted in Python?

Comment: Also see [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'side effect' you are seeing is that `re.split()` will only split on matches that are longer than 0 characters.

The `\s*|:` pattern matches *either* on zero or more spaces, *or* on `:`, **whichever comes first**. But zero spaces *matches everywhere*. In those locations where more than zero spaces matched, the split is made.

Because the `\s*` pattern matches every time a character is considered for splitting, the next option `:` is never considered.

Splitting on non-empty matches is [called out explicitly in the `re.split()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> Note that *split* will never split a string on an empty pattern match.

If you reverse the pattern, `:` *is* considered, as it is the first choice:

```
>>> re.split(':|\s*', 'find  a str:s2')
['find', 'a', 'str', 's2']
```

Comment: So for the first character 'f' in the string, can I say it matches the pattern, but won't be split because it is by "empty pattern match"?

Comment: @Deqing: For `f`, the `\s*` part matches. It is a 0-width match, so no split takes place. Next, `i` is tested, and it too matches `\s*`, etc.

Answer (score -4):

If you meant to do "or" for your matching, then you have to do something like this:
`re.split('(\s*|:)', 'find  a str:s2')`
In short:
"+" means "at least one character".
"*" any (or none)